# Express: Stream an HTML file download from a string in request body

Tags: node.js, express, stream

I have a string `templateString` that is being POSTed to a route in Express. How can this string be streamed as an HTML file and downloaded to the client?

```
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${testname}.html`);
```

^^ This will force the browser to download.

How to take the string in the request and pipe it to the client in the form of an HTML file?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make `Buffer` form the string and send it via `res.end` method.

```
let file = Buffer.from('Your string', 'utf8');

res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    'Content-disposition': `attachment; filename=${testname}.html`,
    'Content-Length': file.length
});

res.end(file);
```

You can read more about `Buffer` [here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer)

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out..
This last simple line seems to work..

```
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${testname}.html`);
res.end(req.body.templateString);
```